# KVO not working for Categories

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

I try to add a property to a class using a category. The property accessors look something like:

```
- (NSArray *)thumbnails {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kThumbnails);
}

- (void)setThumbnails:(NSArray *)thumbnails {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@keypath(self.thumbnails)];
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kThumbnails, thumbnails, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@keypath(self.thumbnails)];
}
```

Unfortunately no notification is triggered. Is it even possible to add KVO compliant properties to categories?

Comment: Show the code that registers the observer and that handles the notification.

Comment: That code where the observer was registered was the problem. It was registered after the notification had already been fired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KVO is definitely possible with accessor methods in categories.

The posted code is KVO compliant for the key `@"thumbnails"`. You should not even have to send the `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` messages.